# Solving Thue equations

Tags: equation-solving, number-theory, diophantine-equations

A Thue equation is a 2-variable homogeneous integer polynomial of degree at least 3. It's well-known that such equations have only finitely many solutions over the integers.

I'm trying to solve some simple Thue equations with `Reduce` but Mathematica is having trouble (no error, it just runs 'forever', or at least hours). Here's an example I pulled from [a test suite](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=pari.git;a=blob;f=src/test/in/thue;h=9254161ac2d9c4d988fecea81409eac2f6a22715;hb=ca2f47bcf845b22451cf9e5fd56f03c176e94412):

```
toSym[P_] := Simplify[y^Exponent[P, x]*P /. x -> (x/y)]
thue[P_, a_Integer] := Simplify[Reduce[toSym[P] == a, {x, y}, Integers]]
thue[x^4 - 13*x^3 - 172*x^2 - 13*x + 1, 9]
```

I can broaden the scope, asking for rational solutions, in which case it gives

> (((x > Root[-20736 - 78978339 #1^4 - 16932890540 #1^8 + 
>              2346433600 #1^12 &, 2] || 
>          x < Root[-20736 - 78978339 #1^4 - 16932890540 #1^8 + 
>              2346433600 #1^12 &, 1] || 
>          Root[-20736 - 78978339 #1^4 - 16932890540 #1^8 + 
>              2346433600 #1^12 &, 1] < x < 
>           Root[-20736 - 78978339 #1^4 - 16932890540 #1^8 + 
>              2346433600 #1^12 &, 2]) && (y == 
>           Root[-9 + x^4 - 13 x^3 #1 - 172 x^2 #1^2 - 13 x #1^3 + #1^4 &,
>             1] || y == 
>           Root[-9 + x^4 - 13 x^3 #1 - 172 x^2 #1^2 - 13 x #1^3 + #1^4 &,
>             2])) || ((x > 
>           Root[-20736 - 78978339 #1^4 - 16932890540 #1^8 + 
>              2346433600 #1^12 &, 2] || 
>          x < Root[-20736 - 78978339 #1^4 - 16932890540 #1^8 + 
>              2346433600 #1^12 &, 1]) && (y == 
>           Root[-9 + x^4 - 13 x^3 #1 - 172 x^2 #1^2 - 13 x #1^3 + #1^4 &,
>             3] || y == 
>           Root[-9 + x^4 - 13 x^3 #1 - 172 x^2 #1^2 - 13 x #1^3 + #1^4 &,
>             4]))) && (x | y) [Element] Rationals

but this isn't a solution -- it doesn't find whether the polynomials have the indicated rational roots or not. In any case I'm actually interested only in the integral solutions. Any ideas?

Edit: I see in [Some Notes on Internal Implementation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#23195) that Mathematica implements the  Tzanakis-de Weger algorithm for Thue equations. Can we trace the behavior of the functions to see if this is being called internally with some sort of `Unprotect` scheme?

Edit 2: I don't think this should take so long to solve -- other systems can solve it in under a second. But I'd like to do this in Mathematica if possible. I suspect that the problem is that Mathematica is stuck on some aspect of the problem not being given to it in the desired format rather than a lack of ability on its part.

Comment: Reduce[x^4 - 172 x^2 y^2 + y^4 == 1, Integers] also drags, while replacing "172" with "5" runs quickly.

Comment: Educated guess: The system is having difficulty computing a system of fundamental units: NumberFieldFundamentalUnits[
 1/4 (13 - Sqrt[865] - Sqrt[2 (509 - 13 Sqrt[865])])] is the problem spot.